# How to check the type of a template parameter for a polymorphic subclass

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

I have a class hierarchy in which `I<T>` and `O<T>` are a templated classes that extend `B` (regular class). `I` aggregates `O` by means of a pointer, like so:

```
class B { ... };
template <class T>
class O : public B
{
    T getValue() { return value; }
private:
    T value;
}
template <class T>
class I : public B
{
    T getValue() { return ptr->getValue(); }
    void setPtr(O<T>* po) { ptr = po; }
private:
    O<T>* ptr;
}
```

The code above is indeed simplified to show only its bare bones. "Connecting" `I` and `O` is done automatically although through user configuration parameters. Because of that, a Singleton table stores polymorphic `B` pointers to all `I` and `O` objects and performs the linking by calling `I::setPtr` as necessary. 
The problem though is that the user can actually mess up and confuse template types of `I` and `O` objects, e.g. user can ask to connect an `I<int>` with an `O<float>`. E.g.:

```
O<int>* oi = new O<int>();
O<float>* of = new O<float>(); 
I<int> ii;
ii.setPtr(oi);  /* This is OK. */
O<int>* oi_wrong = static_cast<O<int>*>((B*)of);  /* This happens. */
ii.setPtr(oi_wrong); /* This is bad. */
```

In order to prevent this sort of behaviour, I included a member variable in both `I` and `O` that stores `typeid(T).name()`, thus allowing to check whether the template parameter is actually the same.

Is there a better way?

**EDIT:** Would there be a better way to do the casting here? Is it not a good idea to store and work with polymorphic pointers in this case?

Comment: if the user is determined to use a reinterpret-cast and static-cast there is very little you can do about it. Your best defence is to make the correct interface so easy and informative to use that users don't try.

Comment: c++ do not prevent you from doing bad things

Comment: @VittorioRomeo well, I mean. You should not check this at all.

Comment: Error is there: `O<int>* oi_wrong = static_cast<O<int>*>((B*)of);`. 
User should have used `dynamic_cast` instead of `static_cast`. So it would have "correct" `nullptr` for his mistake.

Comment: C++ type system prevents mistakes, not abuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really nothing much you can do if your user is going out of the way to misuse your interface - you should (reasonably) design your code without assuming that your user is going to use `static_cast` and `reinterpret_cast` liberally.

In your case, I wouldn't add any additional code/checks. Just assume that your user acts in a reasonable manner.

---

If you really want, you could use `assert` and `dynamic_cast` to check if the passed pointer is actually what you expected in DEBUG builds:

```
struct A { virtual ~A() { } };
struct B : A { };
struct C : A { };

void setPtr(A* po) 
{ 
    assert(dynamic_cast<C*>(po) != nullptr);
}

int main()
{
    B b;
    setPtr((C*)&b); // might trigger assertion
}
```

But I strongly suggest against it, as this is overkill.

Comment: Though the `dynamic_cast` is not guaranteed to help, because the calling code has already invoked undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a friend function for setPtr(), so the user is forced to input fitting types for I and O:

```
    class B { };
    template <typename T>
    class O : public B
    {
    public:
      T getValue() { return value; }
      void setPtr(I<T>& ref_i) { ref_i.ptr = this; };
    private:
      T value;
    };

    template <typename T>
    class I : public B
    {
    public:
      T getValue() { return ptr->getValue(); }
      friend void O::setPtr(I<T>& ref_i)
    private:
      O<T>* ptr;
    };


    int main()
    {
      O<int>* oi = new O<int>();
      O<float>* of = new O<float>();
      I<int> ii;
      of->setPtr(ii);  /* This fails. */
      O<int>* oi_wrong = static_cast<O<int>*>((B*)of);  /* This CAN                 happen. */
      oi->setPtr(ii); /* This is OK. */
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't really help, since `oi_wrong->setPtr(ii);` now has the exact same problem. The issue is the naughty `static_cast`, and not any property of `O` or `I` themselves.